# Execution time of an SQLite Query: Units

Tags: linux, sqlite

As described in [SQLite Documentation](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) one could use:

```
sqlite> .timer ON
```

or add the same command to ~/.sqliterc

When this is done, the SQLite shell responds with user and sys components of CPU Time for every query executed:

```
user@machine% sqlite3 test.db
-- Loading resources from ~/.sqliterc

SQLite version 3.7.14 2012-09-03 15:42:36
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"

sqlite> select count(*) from my_table;
count(*)
10143270
CPU Time: user 0.199970 sys 1.060838
```

While I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20255713/1309045) providing evidence for the units of time being in seconds, I am having a hard time agreeing with it. When timing the execution of a query using a stopwatch, I find almost every query to be taking longer than what the shell times it as taking. For example, the query timed in the above example approximately took a little over **1 minute and 54 seconds** in real time. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

So once again, what are the units? What are **user** and **sys** components?

*I am running SQLite 3.7.14 on a Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.6 (squeeze) distribution accessible over NFS.*

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`user` is the time that the CPU spent executing code in user space (i.e., in the database itself); `sys` is for code in the kernel.

When doing I/O, the CPU spends most of the time waiting.

Sufficiently recent versions of SQLite also show the elapsed real time:

```
SQLite version 3.8.6 2014-08-15 11:46:33
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .timer on
sqlite> UPDATE ...;
Run Time: real 36.591 user 17.362911 sys 1.809612
```

Comment: So the actual time taken to fetch data from db will be sys time?

Comment: @Akshay That depends on what you mean with "actual".

Comment: By actual I mean the time taken to fetch data from db. I guess in the run time, the time to print dta on console is also included.

Comment: The actual time taken is the "real" time. An UPDATE query does not print anything.

Comment: In my case I am trying to find the actual time of select query.